# How to execute an Oracle package via a database link from c++

Tags: c++, oracle, hyperlink, package

```
NB_Pkg_Bonus.NBUpdatePersonalImplements@xxx
                        ('10'
                        ,'0'
                        ,'2020'
                        ,'630000022'
                        ,'2'
                        ,'107382'
                        ,'80881428198'
                        ,'6'
                        ,'1'
                        ,'5'
                        ,'0'
                        ,'1'
                        ,'1'
                        ,'1'
                        );
END;
```

i am doing that from c++ it doest work. but if i execute the same code in sqlDeveloper or toad its work
(xxx is the name of the dbLink)

Comment: in sqldev, you need to add a BEGIN before calling the procedure

Comment: yes and in sqlDev its work but doesnt in c++

Comment: Can you past the part of c++ that includes this code, not just the pl/sql part, and what error are you getting?